# Trigonometric optimization and simplification

Tags: optimization, cuda, gpu, trigonometry

I have the following code snipped that represents the bottleneck in my application:

```
double theta = acos(d);
double a = cos( theta*one_third );
double b = cos( theta*one_third + M_PI_23 );
double c = cos( theta*one_third + M_PI_43 );
```

where `one_third=1.0/3.0`, `M_PI_23=M_PI*2.0/3.0` and `M_PI_43=M_PI*4.0/3.0`.  This is contained in CUDA code, though this same problem is also present in x86.

Anyone know any smart simplifications to the above such that I can avoid the `acos` call and/or the subsequent `cos` calls?  Taken together, they represent 90% of the compute time, with the single `acos` call being about as expensive as three `cos` calls.

Thx

Comment: What is the purpose of this computation? What's the computational context? The computations of 'a', 'b', and 'c' look like they are part of solving a cubic equation in reduced form y**3 + p*y + q = 0, for the case where the original cubic equation has three real solutions and one tries to avoid complex computation.

Comment: This is part of an algorithm that projects an arbitrary 3x3 complex-valued matrix onto the U(3) group.  So yes, there is a connection to solving the cubic equation.

Comment: Never mind then. I was going to suggest to look at Newton's method to find the roots of a cubic equation (particularly useful if you have a rough idea where they might be). A quick perusal of the literature also indicates there might be matrix based methods ("covariance matrix") useful in cases where roots of many cubic polynomials have to be found.

Comment: I actually came to the opposite conclusion.  Computing the analytic solution requires the expensive trig functions.  A faster approach may be to use Newton-Raphson using fast single precision initial guesses using `acosf` and `__sincosf`.

Comment: Instead of `acosf()` you might also want to try a crude approximation such as `sqrtf(-d * 2.21875f + 2.21875f)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[trig](http://www.math.utah.edu/~gupta/MATH1060Fall2012/FormulaSheet.pdf):  cos(A+B) = cosAcosB - sinAsinB

so change this:

```
double a = cos( theta*one_third );
```

to [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_1g8ef2140f246fd2000e964173ca86c798):

```
double as, ac;
sincos( theta*one_third, &as, &ac );
```

and then you can calculate `a`, `b` and `c` as:

```
double a = ac;
double b = ac*cos(M_PI_23) - as*sin(M_PI_23);
double c = ac*cos(M_PI_43) - as*sin(M_PI_43);
```

And of course you should replace `cos(M_PI_xx)` and `sin(M_PI_xx)` with compile-time constants, if possible.  The compiler may figure that out, but it may not.

Here's a worked example demonstrating about 30% speedup (1.3x faster) for a code dominated by this behavior:

```
$ cat t874.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define one_third (1.0/3.0)
// #define M_PI 3.141592654
#define M_PI_23 (M_PI*2.0/3.0)
#define M_PI_43 (M_PI*4.0/3.0)
#define DSIZE 65536
#define nTPB 256
#define NL 100

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

__global__ void tk(double *d, const double smp23, const double cmp23, const double smp43, const double cmp43, const int dsize){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < dsize){
    double theta = acos(d[idx]);
#ifndef USE_I
    d[idx+dsize]   = cos( theta*one_third );
    d[idx+2*dsize] = cos( theta*one_third + M_PI_23 );
    d[idx+3*dsize] = cos( theta*one_third + M_PI_43 );
#else
    double as, ac;
    sincos(theta*one_third, &as, &ac);
    d[idx+dsize]   = ac;
    d[idx+2*dsize] = ac*cmp23 - as*smp23;
    d[idx+3*dsize] = ac*cmp43 - as*smp43;
#endif
  }
}

int main(){

  double *h_d, *d_d;
  cudaMalloc(&d_d, 7*DSIZE*sizeof(double));
  h_d = (double *)malloc(7*DSIZE*sizeof(double));

  double smp23 = sin(M_PI_23);
  double cmp23 = cos(M_PI_23);
  double smp43 = sin(M_PI_43);
  double cmp43 = cos(M_PI_43);
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    h_d[i] = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
  cudaMemcpy(d_d, h_d, DSIZE*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  unsigned long long gtime = dtime_usec(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < NL; i++)
    tk<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(d_d, smp23, cmp23, smp43, cmp43, DSIZE);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  gtime = dtime_usec(gtime);
  cudaCheckErrors("some error");
  printf("elapsed time: %fs\n", gtime/(float)(USECPSEC*NL));
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -O3 t874.cu -o t874
$ ./t874
elapsed time: 0.000078s
$ nvcc -O3 -DUSE_I t874.cu -o t874
$ ./t874
elapsed time: 0.000060s
$
```

Fedora 20, CUDA 7.5RC, Quadro5000 GPU.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella.  I'd missed that identity.  The speedup is there but rather modest at ~10%, since `acos` is so much more expensive than `cos`, and `sincos` is more expensive than just a single `cos`.

Comment: I created a simple test app that showed a 30% speedup using the above optimization.  However it will depend on what GPU you are running on, and whether or not your utilization percentages are accurate.

Comment: If you're really desperate, it might be possible to eliminate the use of `acos` (for this case where you only need the cos of 1/3 of the original angle). This involves solving the trig identity `cos(3A) = 4cos^3(A) - 3cos(A)` for `cos(A)` using the cubic equation [formula](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/) (note that the formula is considerably simpler in this case since the `b` coefficient is zero). That will give you an equation to provide `a` given `d`.  Whether or not that beast with squareroots and cuberoots would be any quicker than the acos function I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  My 10% speedup was from a Quadro M6000, i.e., one with horrible double-precision throughput.  I'll look into the cube root angle (pun intended :) )

Comment: Don't worry.  @njuffa will come along at some point and show you how you can do the whole thing with a shift and an add.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could describe the purpose of this computation, and give us some idea what the surrounding computation looks like. It may be the case that all this trig function computation is largely unnecessary. I usually hit the CRC math tables to look for suitable transformations, I don't recognize the one here. I don't know the performance numbers of the top of my head, something with `atan2()` might work better than `acos()` or some magic with `sqrt()` and `cbrt()` (or their inverses) as Robert Crovella already pointed out.